# Auto refresh/load data only if new data inserted or updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my case, I make auto refresh after X seconds. But I want to make it only refresh when new data inserted or updated.

Here is my script.

*refresh.php*

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#responsecontainer").load("refreshnow.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$("#responsecontainer").load('refreshnow.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 1000);
});
</script>

<div id="responsecontainer"></div>
```

*refreshnow.php*

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from `table`");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
<table style="background:#F0F0F0;" border=1 style="border-collapse:collapse">
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Job</th>
 </tr>
<tbody>
<?php
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$result["name"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$result["job"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
```

So, could it be possible to load new data automatically when new data inserted or updated without refresh after x seconds?

Comment: you would have to break load() into a normal ajax call so you can compare the last fetch to the current one and discard identical returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your existing code, just add another column in a mysql table (if you got a config or settings table, this would be easyer, if not just ad timestamp for each record you insert) with the value time(), this updates the timestamp in the database each time a row is inserted/modified.
Then just do a query like:

```
"select timestamp_column from `settings_table` order by timestamp_column limimt 1"

If ($result["timestamp_column"]+1000>=time()){
       //do the refreshnow.php code here
}
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers